# Google Play Store Alpha Test - app not available for some testers

Tags: android, google-play

We have an app in alpha test. Before we uploaded the apk, we already created a test group and added the email addresses. Now we uploaded the apk and have a download link generated. When we send this link to the testers they cannot download the app, it says the app is not available.

BUT if we now add new testers to the group, those new testers can access the link and download the app.

Why can one set of testers in a group download the app while another set cannot?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic

Answer (score 0):

Yes there are some problems with google playstore.

Can you tell old testers to leave the program if already joined and join again using new link. this may work

*We used alpha testing , our alpha testers has to leave the program to access updated apk from playstore*

Comment: Hey, downvote isn't from me, but what you suggest doesn't work, we have tried that as the first thing ...